# Check Google form responses for certain criteria then email response

Tags: google-apps-script

EDIT: more information. Every special-ed binder requires a review to check for compliance. The review is a 60 plus questionnaire that we turned into a Google form for ease of communication and also to keep data in our district about numbers of binders that are or are not compliant. Well there are really three levels of errors that can occur which need different fixes, from paperwork, to re-training. The goal is that when the form is filled out if an email would be sent depending on what level(s) of error occurred. So if I answered "no" to any question between 6 and 9 then I would get an email stating that a level 1 error was made. Same for level 2 and for level 3 errors. The issue I'm having is that I can only get an email to work when only one error was made or all errors were made. I made a test form, with less questions to test out the coding: https://forms.gle/sM1qWRE7MykVT1Cq6

Also, here is a link to form response spreadsheet so you can get an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YLmIrFO1AK0i0BujwIL1sFVLHuopV0y-cztcykFfpTg/edit?usp=sharing

Finally, here is the code I used for the sample:

```
function sendEmail() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var responses = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var data = responses.getRange(2,1,responses.getLastRow() 
-1,7).getValues();

  Logger.log(data);

  data.forEach(function(row,i) {

   var email = row[1];
   var answer = row[2];
   var replied = row[6];
   var level1 = row[3];
   var level2= row[4];
   var level3 = row[5];

    if (replied == '') {

  //if (level1 == 'No' && level2 =='No' && level3 == 'No') {
      //var body = "The Sped compliance form submitted shows levels 1,2, 
and 3 erorrs. Please review check the district review for further insructions";

      //}

  if (level1 == 'No'){

    Logger.log('yes response');
    Logger.log(email);
    var body = "The SPED compliance check has found a Level 1 error, please see documentation to fix errors.";


  }  
 else if (level2 == 'No') {
   Logger.log("no Response");
   Logger.log(email);
   var body = "The SPED compliance check has found a Level 2 error, please see documentation to fix errors";


  }
else  if (level3 == 'No'){
   var body = "The SPED compliance check has found a Level 3 error, please see documentation to fix errors";

  }
  else {
  }

  var subject = "thank you for submitting your form";

  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);

  var d = new Date();
  responses.getRange(i + 2,7).setValue(d);

    }



  });
```

If a person answers 'No' for any questions in 1-3 then it is a level 1 error, if a person answers 'No' to any questions in 6-9 it is a level 2 error, and if a person answers 'No' to any of the questions in 11-15 it is a level 3 error. I can a response email if there is only 1 error (level 1,2, or 3), however if a person chooses no to more than one set of responses then the code will not work. I'm new to this so I know I'm missing some detail, just not too sure how to get the logic to work.

I have tried adding a clause for if all levels are selected. It didn't work

What I would like to see is that if a person commits a level 1 and other level error that it would show both levels of error.

Comment: Shouldn't you use an Or operator `||` instead of a And operator `&&`?  Otherwise the if will only be true if you answered No to all three levels

Comment: Yes! you're totally correct, thank you. How do I code to differentiate the level of error? Sorry, I'm very new to this and trying to learn. Happy if anyone can share a good video or resource so I can learn.

Comment: You will probably want to use several `else` statements to handle checking for the other levels.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help. I'll look into adding else statements. Just so I can get a good start I'm thinking I would have to write a statement for each possible answer? so 3^2 or nine response strings?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and give some examples of inputs and expected outputs?   As it is, it is a bit unclear what you expect.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your patience and willingness to work with me. I’ll work up an example and try to explain better tomorrow. Unfortunately, I’m worried I just don’t have the right vocabulary yet.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it with a `counter` instead of all those conditions? For example, depending on the Level:

1. Level 1: if the answer is No, `Add 1`
2. Level 2: if the answer is No, `Add 10`
3. Level 3: if the answer is No, `Add 100`

<s>This way you would only need 3 conditions:</s> I edited my code according to yours:

```
 data.forEach(function(row,i, responses) {
    var counter = 0;
    var email = row[1];
    var answer = row[2];
    var replied = row[6];
    var level1 = row[3];
    var level2= row[4];
    var level3 = row[5];


    if (level1 == 'No'){
      counter += 1;
    } 
    if (level2 == 'No'){
      counter += 10;
    }
    if (level3 == 'No'){
      counter += 100;
    }



  if (counter < 10){
    var body = "The SPED compliance check has found a Level 1 error, please see documentation to fix errors.";

  } else if (counter >= 10 && counter < 100){
    var body = "The SPED compliance check has found a Level 2 error, please see documentation to fix errors";

  } else {
    var body = "The SPED compliance check has found a Level 3 error, please see documentation to fix errors";
  }
   var subject = "thank you for submitting your form";

  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);
    var d = new Date();
  responses.getRange(i + 2,7).setValue(d);

  });
```

However, it would be nice to see the rest of your code to figure out how it is developed.

Comment: Thank you, this makes good sense to me. I edited the post and added more info.

Comment: I edited my original answer. However, this might be a bit different if you have several Level1, Level2 and Level3 questions. Also, it will always send the "highest" error level body. For example, answering No to Level 2 and 3 will only send Level 3 email.

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome and I can definitely work with this! I was worried about sending the right email, so, maybe I can just do some conditional formatting on their return sheet or something to identify additional errors.